# Can't upgrade because of kernel dependencies

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, kernel

I get the following error when trying to upgrade:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies :
 linux-image -extra- 3.16.0-73 -generic : Depends : linux-image- 3.16.0-73 -generic but it is not installed
 linux-image -extra- 3.16.0-76 -generic : Depends : linux-image- 3.16.0-76 -generic but it is not is not installed
 linux-image -generic- lts - Utopic : Depends : linux-image- 3.16.0-76 -generic but it is not installed
E : Unmet dependencies . Try to use -f .
```

The Problem is, if I do `apt-get -f install` I get an error that there is not enough disk space. And I checked it... in /boot there is no space left.

So I googled and everyone says, that I need to uninstall old kernel versions to get more space.

However, I *can't* uninstall them, because then I get the same error as when I try to upgrade my system.

It seems like I have a really big problem here. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `aptitude`. You may then try satisfying dependencies at least partially.  That kind of distribution upgrade needs usually three rounds of upgrades, not all of them at once.

Comment: wow, sudo aptitude -f install fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: IMPORTANT: Aptitude resolver will try very hard to satisfy dependencies in non-interactive mode, may thus be time-consuming.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney if you don't mind, you could write an answer with the solution that worked for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `aptitude` in either interactive mode ( `sudo aptitude` ) or non-interactive mode ( `sudo aptitude -f install` followed by `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` ).